# Change a ul to select when going from desktop to mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I change a side menu unordered list to a select drop down when going from desktop to mobile

Comment: Make both the list and the select, then show one or the other using `@media` queries.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do this with media queries which are targeted to viewport size so that you could also trigger this on desktop resized to mobile size.

There are many examples if you google this... for example [responsive menu examples](https://toddmotto.com/building-an-html5-responsive-menu-with-media-queries-javascript/)